What is known about the word problem on free algebraic models?
Consider the fragment of first-order logic with equality and universal quantification as the only logical symbols; we call this logic the logic of universal algebra. I am interested in languages $\mathcal{L}$ with only function or constant symbols (no relations). An $\mathcal{L}$-theory in this logic is usually called an algebraic theory.

What is known about decidable algebraic theories in the logic of universal algebra?

Ideally, I would like a reference that gives many examples of such theories and discusses them at length. For example the theory of groups, abelian groups, and monoids, are all decidable in this sense. (Note that it is important we specify the logic: the theory of groups is undecidable in first-order logic by a result of Tarski).
It is well known that algebraic theories admit free models. For any formula $\forall \bar{x}. \varphi (\bar{x})$ where $\varphi$ is some equality, we see that $T \models \forall \bar{x}. \varphi (\bar{x})$ iff the free $T$-model $F$ generated by $\bar{x}$ satisfies $\varphi(\bar{x})$. This shows that the word problem is solvable for the free models of an algebraic theory $T$ if and only if $T$ is decidable (in the logic of universal algebra). Hence we can ask an equivalent question.

What is known about the word problem on free algebraic models?

(To continue the example, note that the word problem for groups is undecidable in general, but the word problem for free groups is clearly solvable)

Have you looked at ALGORITHMIC PROBLEMS IN VARIETIES, by Kharlampovich and Sapir? Many examples are discussed there.
